# Как распараллелить потоки и почему не помогает синхронизация?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Задача в том чтобы 2 или 3, или 10 тредов(неважно), поочереди(каждый тред поочереди через одну секунду) декрементировали переменную. Сначала просто писал метод и синхронизировал его, потом по объекту делал синхронизацию, тепер делаю все напрямую в методе run, но все равно все треды работают пачкой, и только после выполнения одной итерации, обратно же, все вместе пачкой засыпают. Как последовательно разделить работу? почему синхронизщация не помагает?

```
package nhg;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class qq {
    public static void main (  String [] args ) throws UnknownHostException, InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            new The().start();
        }
    }

    public static class The extends Thread {
        private volatile static int q = 10;

        private final Object lock;

        The(){
            lock = new Object();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (q = 10; q > 0; q--) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("qqq");
                    }
                    System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " lift vniz " + q);
                }
                Thread.yield();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вот в чём: каждый поток  лочит под свой `lock`, соответственно надо сделать `lock` статическим объектом класса `The` таким образом синхронизация должна заработать. Хотя синхронизация здесь не верный вариант: пока поток будет спать другой поток не сможет войти в метод, чтобы решить эту проблему стоит перенести синхронизацию чисто к уменьшению переменной:

```
public void run() {
           while(q > 0){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("qqq");
                }
                synchronized(lock) {
                    q--;
                }
                System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " lift vniz " + q);
            }
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
```

Однако в таком случае переменная может уйти в минус так-как два потока считаю её параллельно, обойти можно отдельным методом:

```
public static synchronized boolean decr()
{
    if(q > 0)
    {
        q--;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void run()
{
    while(decr())
    {
         System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " lift vniz " + q);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    Thread.yield();
}
```

Comment: Так и решил, проблема была в статике) ну все равно большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            new The().start();
        }
    }

    public static class The extends Thread {

        private volatile static int q = 10;
        public static synchronized void incrementCount() {
            q--;
        }
        private final Object lock;

        The() {
            lock = new Object();
        }

        void print() {
            for (q = 10; q > 0; incrementCount()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("qqq");
                    }
                    System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " lift vniz " + q);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                print();
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}
```

вывод

```
Thread-0 lift vniz 10
Thread-1 lift vniz 9
Thread-0 lift vniz 8
Thread-1 lift vniz 7
Thread-0 lift vniz 6
Thread-1 lift vniz 5
Thread-0 lift vniz 4
Thread-1 lift vniz 3
Thread-0 lift vniz 2
Thread-1 lift vniz 1
Thread-0 lift vniz 0
```

Comment: мне надо чтобы раз в одну секунду любой трэд уменьшил q и вывел это на экран... важно чтобы трэд был не один

Comment: @alexsafsafsd а в результате что ? не очень понял, что вы хотите

Comment: Хочу сделать обычный счетчик, чтобы любой трэд раз в секнду уменьшал значение q и это отображалось. Целью является понять почему мой вариант не работает, почему треды работают группами, выполнили run вместе и заснули, и выяснить почему синхронизация по объекту не работает. А также понять как разделить работу трэдов на данном примере.